# Where to place Form (server side) tag so that it will not effect CSS of web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have created a master page with header, footer, and container(for content of other pages). Footer has a 'asp.net link button' which requires `<form id="form1" runat="server">`. Now I have to add content in 'content page' such as 'asp buttons' 'links' etc. But 'IIS' generates error that

> 'a webpage can have only one server side tag.'

In **master-page**, I've placed  `<form id="form1" runat="server">`under the `<div class="footer-right">` tag and if I try to move `<form id="form1" runat="server">` to the top of page or any where else, the CSS of search bar gets vanished. How to resolve this issue?

[image]

> if I place 'form tag' on the top of page after body tag.

[image]

here is my code

> master-page

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    

    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
 <meta name="keywords" content="footer, search, form, icons" />

 <title>Homepage</title>


    <%--<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>--%>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/footer-distributed-with-search.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial;
        }


        .topnav {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #37312f;
            padding: 12px 14px;
            font-family:sans-serif;
            font-weight:bold;
        }

            .topnav a {
                float: left;
                color: #f2f2f2;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 12px 14px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-size: 17px;
            }

                .topnav a.logo {
                    font-size: 25px;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    color: #fff;
            height: 12px;
            margin-left: 72px;
        }

        .topnav-right {
            float: right;
        }


        .active {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
        }

        .topnav .icon {
            display: none;
        }

        .dropdown1 {
            float: left;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

            .dropdown1 .dropbtn {
                font-size: 17px;
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                color: white;
                padding: 12px 14px;
                background-color: inherit;
                font-family: inherit;
                margin: 0;
            }

        .dropdown1-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
            z-index: -de1;
        }

            .dropdown1-content a {
                float: none;
                color: black;
                padding: 12px 14px;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                text-align: left;
            }

        .topnav a:hover, .dropdown1:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: #555;
            color: white;
        }

        .dropdown1-content a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
            color: black;
        }

        .dropdown1:hover .dropdown1-content {
            display: block;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown1 .dropbtn {
                display: none;
            }

            .topnav a.icon {
                float: right;
                display: block;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .topnav.responsive {
                position: relative;
            }

                .topnav.responsive .icon {
                    position: absolute;
                    right: 0;
                    top: 0;
                }

                .topnav.responsive a {
                    float: none;
                    display: block;
                    text-align: left;
                }

                .topnav.responsive .dropdown1 {
                    float: none;
                }

                .topnav.responsive .dropdown1-content {
                    position: relative;
                }

                .topnav.responsive .dropdown1 .dropbtn {
                    display: block;
                    width: 100%;
                    text-align: left;
                }
        }

    </style>


</head>



<body>
   <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <a href="#default" class="logo">Website Name</a>
            <div class="topnav-right">
                <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
                <div class="dropdown1">
                    <button class="dropbtn">
                        Tools
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown1-content">
                        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <a href="#about">About Us</a>
                <a href="#news">Contact</a>
                <a href="#contact">Login</a>
                <a href="#about">Sign Up</a>


                <%--Dropdown bar for window resize--%>
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a> 
            </div> <%--id="Topnav-right--%>
          </div>   <%--id="myTopnav--%>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
                if (x.className === "topnav") {
                    x.className += " responsive";
                } else {
                    x.className = "topnav";
                }
            }
        </script>

    
        <!-- The content of your page would go here. -->
         <div class="container" style="background-color:aquamarine">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    


     <footer class="footer-distributed">

   <div class="footer-left">

    <p class="footer-links">
     <a href="#">Home</a>
     ·
     <a href="#">About us</a>
     ·
     <a href="#">Contact</a>
     ·
     <a href="#">Login</a>
     ·
     <a href="#">Sign up</a>
     ·
     <a href="#">Feedback</a>
    </p>

    <p class="footer-company-name">websiteName &copy; 2019</p>

   </div>

   <div class="footer-right">

    <form id="form2" runat="server" method="get" action="#">
     <input placeholder="Search our website" name="search" /><asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-mini" OnClick="Page_Load">
                        <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></asp:LinkButton>
     <%--<i class="fa fa-search"></i>--%>
    </form>
   </div>
  </footer>


</body>
</html>
```

> Content-page

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm5555555555555555.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm5555555555555555" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    
    
    
    <%--<form is="form1" runat="server">--%>
    
    
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-4</div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-4</div>
  </div>
            <h2>Responsive Topnav with Dropdown</h2>
            <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
            <p>Hover over the dropdown button to open the dropdown menu.</p>


           <%-- </form>--%>


</asp:Content>
```

> footer-distributed-with-search.css

```css
.footer-distributed{
 background-color: #292c2f;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 font: bold 16px sans-serif;
 text-align: left;

 padding: 50px 60px;
 margin-top: 80px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

/* Footer left */

.footer-distributed .footer-left{
 float: left;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links{
 color:  #ffffff;
 margin: 0 0 10px;
 padding: 0;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-links a{
 display:inline-block;
 line-height: 1.8;
 text-decoration: none;
 color:  inherit;
}

.footer-distributed .footer-company-name{
 color:  #8f9296;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 0;
}


/* Footer right */

.footer-distributed .footer-right{
 float: right;
}

/* The search form */

.footer-distributed form{
 position: relative;
}

.footer-distributed form input{
 display: block;
 border-radius: 3px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background-color:  #1f2022;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 border: none;

 font: inherit;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color:  #d1d2d2;

 width: 500px;
 padding: 18px 50px 18px 18px;
}

.footer-distributed form input:focus{
 outline: none;
}

/* Changing the placeholder color */

.footer-distributed form input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 color:  #5c666b;
}

.footer-distributed form input::-moz-placeholder {
 opacity: 1;
 color:  #5c666b;
}

.footer-distributed form input:-ms-input-placeholder{
 color:  #5c666b;
}

/* The magnify glass icon */

.footer-distributed form i{
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 16px;
 right: 18px;

 color: #d1d2d2;
 font-size: 18px;
}

/* If you don't want the footer to be responsive, remove these media queries */

@media (max-width: 1000px) {

 .footer-distributed form input{
  width: 300px;
 }

}

@media (max-width: 800px) {

 .footer-distributed{
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 14px sans-serif;
 }

 .footer-distributed .footer-company-name{
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
 }

 .footer-distributed .footer-left,
 .footer-distributed .footer-right{
  float: none;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .footer-distributed .footer-left{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

 .footer-distributed form input{
  width: 100%;
 }

}
```

> CSS template I've used
>   [Beautiful and Responsive Footer Templates](https://tutorialzine.com/2015/01/freebie-5-responsive-footer-templates)

Comment: Your Masterpage probably has a Form tag as well. If you want to do multiple Form tags, remove the `runat="server"` attribute and use plain HTML input tags instead.

Comment: `runat="server"`cannot be removed. because imagelink button  `<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-mini" OnClick="Page_Load">` requires 'form' element with `runat="server"` property

Comment: Generally webform pages have only a single form tag and everything goes inside it.

Comment: the main problem is: if I move `<form id="form2" runat="server" method="get" action="#">` to the  top of the page right after <body> tag. The css of search bar gets removed

Comment: @Emmy Place your `<form>` tag after `<body>` and close your `</form>` before `</body>` on your master page.

Comment: I've tried this as well but its not working. Search bar's css gets vanished. if you have solution then post as an answer

Comment: @Emmy Did my answer help to resolve your problem?

Comment: Actually,   is problem with CSS file.`.footer-distributed form{
 position: relative;`
}. I am updating my question for better understanding.

Comment: @Emmy So did you get this resolved or is it still happening?

Comment: Thank you for your time. I've resolved it my self.The problem was with CSS file.`.footer-distributed form{ position: relative; }. ` 'form tag was inheriting css from  'footer-distributed' So I've updated css of text box and search button.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the style sheets included in your master page are using relative paths. Specify your style sheet links with `runat=server` and prefix them with the virtual web root path (~). 
An example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/demo.css" runat="server"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/footer-distributed-with-search.css" runat="server"/>
```

Do this for all your style sheets on your page (obviously not the CDN links) and place your `<form>` after `<body>` and please ensure that the `<head>` element also needs to be `runat=server`. Using the virtual web root path (~) will work when you publish your site in a virtual directory so you don't encounter problems as such.